# Python:The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
try:
    masterpath = os.path.join(path, "master.txt") 
    with open(masterpath, 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
    f.close()
    exec(s)
    with open(masterpath, 'w') as g:
        g.truncate()
    g.close()
    os.remove(masterpath)
```

Here I want to read something in a .txt file and then erase content and delete it. But it always shows it cannot delete it as 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'.
Actually what I need is to delete the .txt file, but it cannot delete immediately sometimes, so I erase the content at first in case that it will be read again. So is there any good way to read something in a .txt file and then delete this file as soon and stable as possible?

Comment: Has this been resolved? I saw lower on the page you said even when you remove the unnecessary .close() calls, it still refuses to delete the file? Did you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You **should NOT** call `f.close()` nor `g.close()`. It is called automatically by `with` statement.

Comment: Actually after I erase .close, it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

remove the unnecessary `close()` statements to start - like @grapes mentioned - why are you truncating what you are deleting? just delete it...

```
try:
    masterpath = os.path.join(path, "master.txt") 
    with open(masterpath, 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
    exec(s)
except Error as e:
    print(e)
else:
    os.remove(masterpath)
```

FYI, it is bad form to execute the contents of a file if you do not control the contents of said file.

another option:

```
masterpath = os.path.join(path, "master.txt") 
with open(masterpath, 'r') as f:
    try:        
        s = f.read()            
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        exec(s)
os.remove(masterpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use short sleep in exception part:

```
    try:
        masterpath = os.path.join(path, "master.txt") 
        with open(masterpath, 'r') as f:
            s = f.read()
        f.close()
        exec(s)
        with open(masterpath, 'w') as g:
            g.truncate()
        g.close()
        os.remove(masterpath)
   except WindowsError:
            time.sleep(sleep)
        else:
            break
```

Another way is to use:

```
os.remove(masterpath)
```

Comment: Sorry what is another way？ Could you explain a little bit？

Comment: @Andy  Try adding a retry loop with a short sleep around your `os.remove` call.